# Instanton homology - reference request

Tags: floer-homology

What is the best reference for someone (i.e. me) trying to learn Instanton Floer homology? Assume I already know symplectic Floer homology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Donaldson's book

http://books.google.com/books?id=CbMq-dh8nEoC&pg=PA106&dq=simon+donaldson+floer+yang&hl=en&ei=hFPkTMWtM4WnnAep1LzXDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false